# Gunicorn cant find the static files

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

By using gunicorn without nginx from [digitalcloud tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-and-configure-a-new-django-project)
my server is runing and on the console is

```
not found: /static/style.css
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

I already tried to

1. collectstatic
2. do `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` in urls.py file
3. makemigrations + migrate

Comment: With DEBUG=False Django does not serve static files.

Answer (score 0):

maybe django try read 'static//static/style.css' but you need this: 'style.css' ;) ?

Comment: in html I am connecting like {% static 'style.css' %} works on localhost

Comment: I used this conf: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) , STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Comment: BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

Comment: look in your nginx.conf you have ?  location /static/ { alias /home/projects/nameproject/static/; }

Comment: but when I am runing with runserver 0.0.0.0:port, the static files are still not working

Answer (score 0):

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

urlpatterns = [your urls here] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update Nginx config for fixing this issue? if not working why don't you try Django package [Whitenoise](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is easy to install and easy to use if you followed the instructions.

some simplified steps:

1. Collect static - make sure static files existing

   ```
    python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
2. Install the Whitenoise - this step depends how you managed the packages, update proper file(e.g. Pipfile or requirements.txt) and install. Below command just a example to install the package, might not suits your project.

   ```
    pip install whitenoise
   ```
3. Add the following `STATICFILES_STORAGE` in settings.py - this will compress and cache the static files(from Whitenoise [docs](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#add-compression-and-caching-support))

   ```
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
   ```
4. Add the following to your `MIDDLEWARE` in settings.py - from Whwitenoise docs, Whitenoise package should place after `django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware`

   ```
    `MIDDLEWARE = [
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', #add it here exactly after security middleware
      ...
    ]
   ```
5. now restart or rebuild the app to check whether it is working for you.

**Please check Whitenoise docs if you running into issue about installing the Whitenoise**

a message for using `staticfiles_urlpatterns`:
**this only works when `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py` which means you should NOT use it for production environment.** see reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns)

Answer (score -1):

You can create in your project folder settings then in them create settings files like names:
local.py

```
from my_project.settings import *
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

this run in VM like: python manage.py runserver --settings settings.local

remember in urls add:

```
if settings.DEBUG == True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

web.py

```
from my_project.settings import *
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["www.side.com", "side.com"]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and then in gunicorn import only web.py file project to read in nginx

this run in VPS server.

Comment: yeah I know about that, but it is not solving static files problem